# Allure reports. Is there a way to write feature description?

Tags: report, gherkin, allure

I'm a newcomer in using Allure.
Is there a way to write feature description in addition to the name?

I mean, not only @Feature ("Editing user"), but something like 
"As admin 
I want to change a member info. 
So that I fill a new data on its card, and the member can be found using the new data."?

And maybe there is an Allure plugin to write Gherkin-like scenarios and show them in allure reports as user stories?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add descriptions to features. Try to use more informative feature names.

For gherkin-like scenarios you can use test framework which has support for it. For example `cucumber-jvm` (You can find Allure cucumber-jvm adaptor here: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you use cucumber Allure plugin.

Maven repo: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.kirlionik%7Callure-cucumber-plugin%7C1.0.1%7Cjar

GitHub wiki: https://github.com/kirlionik/allure-cucumber-plugin/wiki

Description will be display in each scenario before steps